# Imagecreatefromjpeg has problems with reading some jpeg files

Tags: php

When i want to create a thumbnail with php and gd library :

```
$quelle = imagecreatefromjpeg($bild["pfad"]);
$ziel = imagecreatetruecolor($neuebreite,$neuehoehe);
imagecopyresampled($ziel,$quelle,0,0,0,0,$neuebreite,$neuehoehe,$bild['breite'],$bild['hoehe']);
imagejpeg($ziel,"thumbnail/".$nummer."-".$bildid."-temp.jpg",80);
```

However these warnings occur:

> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: in /public_html/swupload.php on line 1
>   Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): 'uploads/sw/s12010-1_s s_Jakob.jpeg' is not a valid JPEG file in /public_html/swupload.php on line 1
>   Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /public_html/swupload.php on line 3

(the image is there and the path is right)
With other pictures it work fine!
It works also with `cmyk` files.

The only Problem are some jpeg files.

How can I support also these?

Comment: my guess is that the `jpeg` is `cmyk` and not `rgb`

Comment: I converted the same file into `cmyk` and it worked